# Exception on SG SIII and Note 2 with JB update while using Contacts API

Tags: android, sqlite, contactscontract

I'm developing an app that uses Android Contacts API.
My code works ok but recently new errors in Play Market Feedback started to appear.
Looks like theese errors show up only on SGS3 and Note2.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":<phonenumber>": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT times_contacted, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, phonetic_name, phonetic_name_style, ((CASE WHEN raw_contact_linkpriority1 > 0 THEN link_type1||'|' ELSE '' END)||(CASE WHEN raw_contact_linkpriority2 > 0 THEN link_type2||'|' ELSE '' END)||(CASE WHEN raw_contact_linkpriority3 > 0 THEN link_type3||'|' ELSE '' END)||(CASE WHEN raw_contact_linkpriority4 > 0 THEN link_type4||'|' ELSE '' END)||(CASE WHEN raw_contact_linkpriority5 > 0 THEN link_type5 ELSE '' END)) AS link, is_user_profile, snippet, raw_contact_linkpriority4, lookup, raw_contact_linkpriority5, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, sec_custom_vibration, last_time_contacted, _id, photo_uri, display_name_source, photo_thumb_uri, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, photo_id, send_to_voicemail, display_name_alt AS display_name_reverse, name_raw_contact_id, custom_ringtone, photo_file_id, has_phone_number, link_type5, link_type4, link_type3, link_type2, contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, link_type1, raw_contact_linkpriority3, display_name, raw_contact_linkpriority2, raw_contact_linkpriority1, sort_key_alt, has_email, in_visible_group, dirty_contact, starred, link_count, sort_key, display_name_alt, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts FROM view_contacts_restricted JOIN (SELECT contact_id AS snippet_contact_id, ifnull('['||(SELECT MIN(data1) FROM data JOIN raw_contacts ON (data.raw_contact_id = raw_contacts._id) JOIN phone_lookup ON data._id=phone_lookup.data_id WHERE search_index.contact_id=contact_id AND normalized_number LIKE '%+<phonenumber>%' OR normalized_number LIKE '%+<phonenumber>%')||']',snippet(search_index,'[',']','...',1,-10)) AS snippet FROM search_index WHERE search_index MATCH content:<phonenumber>* OR name:2024121E20201E14122412* UNION SELECT contact_id AS snippet_contact_id, NULL AS snippet FROM phone_lookup JOIN raw_contacts ON ( raw_contacts._id=raw_contact_id) WHERE normalized_number LIKE '%+<phonenumber>%') ON (_id=snippet_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (_id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:184)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 4 more
```

Comment: <phonenumber> is actually a phonenumber of a contact that user searches

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteException: near ":<phonenumber>": syntax error ... while compiling:
... WHERE search_index MATCH content:<phonenumber>* OR name:2024121E20201E14122412* ...
```

`MATCH` works on strings. The code forgot to put quotes around them, like this:

```
... MATCH 'content:<phonenumber>* OR name:2024121E20201E14122412*' ...
```

This appears to be a bug in that version of Android's Contact Content Provider.

Comment: Then why this exception appears only on that two devices running JB?

Comment: mUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
That is how sql request is made.

Comment: Same error with my app.
@nixan: Did you find a solution or an answer why this error occurs?